# How do I turn on Bluetooth on Dell Inspiron 15 300 series?

Tags: windows-7

I don't know how to turn on Bluetooth on my laptop; Dell Inspiron 15 300 series. I have tried a lot but I am not getting the option how to turn the Bluetooth on.

Answer (score 1):

Source [Connect to a Bluetooth Device From Your Dell Computer in Windows 7](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN129493/en)

Locate the Bluetooth icon in the lower-right corner of the computer screen.

The Bluetooth icon may be hidden, click the Show hidden icons arrow to show any hidden icons.

[image]

If there is no icon see [How to Download and Install a Driver?](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN128938/en#Issue4)

Answer (score 1):

I had disabled the bluetooth on my Dell Inspiron 3000 series, because it was connecting to Bluetooth devices when I didn't want it too.  But now I wanted it back on, and couldn't remember how to do it.  Luckily I figured it out on my own.  This is how I found it.

1. At the startup menu, search for "device manager"
2. Look on the list for Bluetooth Radios
3. I clicked on "Dell Wireless 1705 Bluetooth"
4. There should be a screen that shows if you device is enabled or disabled.  Click "enable".